# When is the central limit theorem not applied?

Tags: r, distributions, statistical-significance, nonparametric, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to compare two matched samples. In total I have a sample of 34 people. Each patient receives two treatments, a C1 treatment and a C2 treatment. So each patient will be compared to himself according to different parameters. Some of my variables are normally distributed while others are not (or even not unimodal). Can a parametric test based on the central limit theory be used (as my sample size >30)?

See below the distribution of each variable.

[image]

Comment: `(Andrew Gelman) As you know from teaching introductory statistics, 30 is infinity.`

Comment: But seriously, what is your hypothesis and how will you test it?

Comment: It is not a confirmatory study. It is just exploratory. The objectif is to compare the means between the two groups et prove that their means are different

Comment: In any case, if this is exploratory a simple t-test will do unless you have skewed data or something.